# How to read javascript array values php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Here i am passing the javascript array values to php using the jquery ajax.now i want to recive the data in php script. how should i do it?

php:

```
<?php
$list = array
(
//here i want to get the ajax array data
);

$t = time();
$file = fopen("xls/$t-userinput-input.csv","w");

foreach ($list as $line)
  {
  fputcsv($file,explode(',',$line));
  }

fclose($file); ?>
```

Jquery:

```
function arrayPush(val1,val2) {
    uservalues.push(val1,val2);   
    passvalues()
}


function passvalues(){
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       data: {info:uservalues},
       url: "write.php",
       success: function(msg){
         alert("Thankyou")
       }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you're `POST`ing the data, just try with:

```
$list = $_POST['info'];
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, read it from PHP POST variable:

```
$jsonRawData = $_POST['info']
```

Next, decode it to have php array - http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

```
$decoded = json_decode($jsonRawData);
```

You can always peek what's inside PHP variable with var_dump.